# Pagelatch while olap cibe partition is processing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, vmware, ssas-2008

At virtual machine (vmware) with 64 gb ram, 32 cpu 2.9 hhz, 1.4 tb memory (400 gb + 150 gb + 1 tb) we have db with size 150 gb (at 1 tb disk with tempdb and other db). When we start processing last date from fact table (have all needed indexes) in olap cube ms sql always throw query to pagelatch.  Is there any tips to solve this? I'm gonna split table to partition with different file groups. May be db should have another location at virtual machine or sql server version should be last? (Windows server 2008 r2, ms sql server enterprise 2008r2).

Thanks.

Comment: Solve what? Latching? Have you googled 'SQL Latching'?

Comment: I've googled. I know what this type of wait time is mean. I've just asked about right organization virtual machine as sql server. May be this is the problem. My table have more 150 mln rows and select for 8 hours is very long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem using ms sql partition function,  partition scheme. Now table has 14 partitions in different file groups and files.